# IOS Equivalent of Android Monitor

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I was trying to get ui element object for an ios application in python using appium. For android, it's very simple, we can use android monitor to view 'View heirarchy' and all ui elements along with its attributes like text, resource-id etc. Is there an equivalent of android ui automator in ios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I swear by [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) for inspecting both platforms.